# Getting Ext.JSON.decode() to parse .net datetime strings that look like "/Date(0000000000000-0000)/"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, extjs, dst

I've got some serialized json containing timestamps like:

`"TimeStamp": "/Date(1362898800000-0700)/",`

Which, when parsed correctly, is supposed to be:

`Sat Mar 09 2013 23:59:59 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)`

But its being parsed as

`Sat Mar 09 2013 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)`

I've got a couple questions, the first of which may help answer the second:

A) What is this format called?

B) How can I get Ext.JSON.decode() to parse these strings properly, or what format should I change it to from .NET, to get Ext.js to handle it properly?

I've searched and only found http://evilcroco.name/2010/12/make-extjs-parse-net-date-format-in-json/ but it's a little out of date. I'm just looking for a point in the right direction, and will update with code as I go.

**Bonus Question!**

What are some best practices or standards for plotting data on a chart in a timezone where daylight savings time is observed? Should it be converted to UTC?

Comment: bonus answer to bonus question -> **YES**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the date has been parsed correctly it the culture that is making the difference. you are parsing the date at the client side so its taking into account your current culture which is `-7` from the GMT.

consider saving all your dates in UTC, it never too late, once the application grows these date time issue go out of hand.

since you are using .net you can consider using [noda time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time)

here is an excellent SO answer which might help you [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices)